# How to run a Talend .jar job on Airflow?

Tags: python, jar, airflow, talend, airflow-scheduler

Hello people of the Earth! I'm using **Airflow** to schedule and run .jar Job generated with **Talend Open Studio BigData**,i added my job as a DAG in Airflow by making a `.py` file under `AIRFLOW_HOME/dags` :

from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
    from datetime import datetime

```
import os
import sys


bib_app = "/home/user/Images/JObforAirflow/test/test_run.sh"
default_args = {
    'owner': 'yabid',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 30),
    'provide_context': True}

args = {
  'owner': 'yabid',
  'start_date': datetime(2019, 4, 25),
  'provide_context': True}

dag = DAG('run_jar', 
default_args=default_args,
description='Dag for batch job')



t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='dependency',
    bash_command= bib_app,
    dag=dag)


t2 = BashOperator(
 task_id = 't2',
 dag = dag,
 bash_command = 'java -cp /home/user/Images/JObforAirflow/test/jobbatch.jar'
 )

t1.set_upstream(t2)
```

but when i run manualy my dag it failed automatically

the job works perfcty on Talend,

```
here is the log file generated by Airflow :
*** Reading local file: /home/user/airflow/logs/run_jar/t2/2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00/1.log
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,262] {__init__.py:1139} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: run_jar.t2 2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,266] {__init__.py:1139} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: run_jar.t2 2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00 [queued]>
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,266] {__init__.py:1353} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,266] {__init__.py:1354} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,266] {__init__.py:1355} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,323] {__init__.py:1374} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): t2> on 2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,323] {base_task_runner.py:119} INFO - Running: [u'airflow', u'run', 'run_jar', 't2', '2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00', u'--job_id', '22', u'--raw', u'-sd', u'DAGS_FOLDER/run_jar.py', u'--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpd_yKoR']
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,761] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2 [2019-04-30 17:37:10,760] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,933] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2 [2019-04-30 17:37:10,932] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/user/airflow/dags/run_jar.py
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,945] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2 [2019-04-30 17:37:10,945] {cli.py:517} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: run_jar.t2 2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00 [running]> on host user-OptiPlex-3020
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,954] {bash_operator.py:81} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,954] {bash_operator.py:90} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=t2
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=run_jar
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2019-04-30T16:36:48.390314+00:00
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,955] {bash_operator.py:104} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmp8m82nT/t2_l6p9W
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,955] {bash_operator.py:114} INFO - Running command: java -cp /home/user/Images/JObforAirflow/test/jobbatch.jar
[2019-04-30 17:37:10,959] {bash_operator.py:123} INFO - Output:
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - Syntaxe : java [-options] class [args...]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -            (pour l'exécution d'une classe)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -    ou  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -            (pour l'exécution d'un fichier JAR)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - où les options comprennent :
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -d32      utilisez le modèle de données 32 bits s'il est disponible
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,020] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -d64      utilisez le modèle de données 64 bits s'il est disponible
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -server   pour sélectionner la machine virtuelle "server"
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -zero     pour sélectionner la machine virtuelle "zero"
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -dcevm    pour sélectionner la machine virtuelle "dcevm"
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   La machine virtuelle par défaut est server,
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   car vous exécutez une machine de classe de serveur.
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - 
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - 
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   Liste de répertoires, d'archives JAR et
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                    d'archives ZIP séparés par des :, dans laquelle rechercher les fichiers de classe.
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,021] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -D<name>=<value>
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   définition d'une propriété système
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   activation de la sortie en mode verbose
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -version      impression de la version du produit et fin de l'opération
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -version:<value>
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   Avertissement : cette fonctionnalité est en phase d'abandon et sera enlevée
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   dans une version future.
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   exécution de la version spécifiée obligatoire
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -showversion  impression de la version du produit et poursuite de l'opération
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   Avertissement : cette fonctionnalité est en phase d'abandon et sera enlevée
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,022] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   dans une version future.
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   inclusion/exclusion des environnements JRE privés de l'utilisateur dans la recherche de version
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -? -help      impression du message d'aide
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -X            impression de l'aide sur les options non standard
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   activation des assertions avec la granularité spécifiée
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   désactivation des assertions avec la granularité spécifiée
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -esa | -enablesystemassertions
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   activation des assertions système
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,023] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   désactivation des assertions système
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   chargement de la bibliothèque d'agent natif <libname>, par exemple -agentlib:hprof
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   voir également, -agentlib:jdwp=help et -agentlib:hprof=help
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   chargement de la bibliothèque d'agent natif via le chemin d'accès complet
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   chargement de l'agent du langage de programmation Java, voir java.lang.instrument
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -     -splash:<imagepath>
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO -                   affichage de l'écran d'accueil avec l'image spécifiée
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,024] {bash_operator.py:127} INFO - Voir http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html pour plus de détails.
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,027] {bash_operator.py:131} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,031] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 135, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,032] {__init__.py:1611} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2 Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/bin/airflow", line 32, in <module>
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     args.func(args)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 74, in wrapper
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     return f(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 523, in run
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     _run(args, dag, ti)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 442, in _run
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,094] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     pool=args.pool,
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 135, in execute
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2     raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
[2019-04-30 17:37:11,095] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 22: Subtask t2 airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2019-04-30 17:37:15,446] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2019-04-30 17:37:15,445] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I've tried e to connect everything together, i don't know where is the main error, the job works perfectly on Talend so the error is not from the Job in question.
Maybe someone used it before and has working example.
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

When you build a job in Talend Studio it generates `.sh` (for *nix) and `.bat` (for Windows) files as well as the `.jar` file. You will want to call/execute the `.sh` rather than the `.jar` file directly as it will contain the Java settings you set within Talend.

So your `bash_command` should be something like `bash_command = 'bash /home/user/Images/JObforAirflow/test/jobbatch.sh'`.

*Be aware you may need to allow the `.sh` to be executable, i.e. `chmod +x file.sh`. Also it may be worth executing the `.sh` file from the terminal (not in Airflow) to make sure it works happily outside Talend Studio.*

Answer (score 0):

We run Talend jobs deployed on TAC's Job Conductor from Airflow by calling the MetaServlet script. This way you not only run Talend jobs from Airflow, but can also leverage features of TAC to see logs, history of runs, real time statistics etc .,

```
tac_job_run_command = "/opt/tomcat/webapps/tac/WEB-INF/classes/MetaServletCaller.sh --tac-url=http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/tac/ --json-params='{"actionName":"runTask","authPass":"Password123","authUser":"talend@talend.com","taskId":123,"mode":"synchronous"}' "

talend_job_task = SSHOperator(
    task_id='talend_job_task',
    ssh_conn_id='talend_tac_server',
    command=tac_job_run_command,
    do_xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)
```

We use an SSHOperator to connect to the TAC Server and run the metaservlet script with the credentials and parameters needed. I would suggest reading Edward Ost's blog on using the Metaservlet (http://edwardost.github.io/talend/di/2015/05/28/Using-the-TAC-API/)

**Note**: I have created an Airflow connection named "talend_tac_server" with connection credentials for my TAC server.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `PythonOperator`.
Inside the PythonOperator there is a custom code which extract the zip and launch the .sh with the special command: `subprocess.Popen`.
It has been useful to handle the errors inside the custom code.